# String match with 'in'

Tags: python

In the following code, I would like to search a match for elements in a list in a given string.

```
lst1 = ['LOP3', 'FOO']
lst2 = ['PLOP3', 'BAR']

x = 'LOP3.LUT'
y = 'PLOP3.LUT'

for i1 in lst1:
    if i1 in x:
        print('yes1')
    if i1 in y:
        print('yes2')

for i2 in lst2:
    if i2 in x:
        print('yes3')
    if i2 in y:
        print('yes4')
```

When I run the code, I see

```
yes1
yes2
yes4
```

That means `lst1[0]` is found in `y` which results in `yes2`. That is wrong in my case. `x` doesn't start with `PLOP3` although it has `LOP3` in its name. So, I would like to see `yes1, yes4` only. How can I fix that code?

Comment: For this particular case, you can use `if x.startswith(i1)` instead of `in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"That means LOP3 is found in lst1[0] which results in yes2."

No, `lst1[0]`, `'LOP3'`, is found in `y`, `'PLOP3.LUT'`. Other way around. That causes it to print `yes2`. So perhaps you want to reverse that expression, `a in b` to `b in a`?

Or perhaps you want the startswith method, e.g. `if x.startswith(i1):`?

Comment: `b in a` (`x in i1`) doesn't make much sense in this case.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I don't know what this code is for, I'm just going by the phrasing in the (first draft of) the question, and trying to tease out some clarity :)